# Category product re-indexing not working in magento 1.8

Tags: php, mysql, magento, indexing

I am getting

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (database_name.catalog_category_product_index, CONSTRAINT
>   FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID FOREIGN KEY
>   (product_id) REFERENCES catalog_product_entity (entity_id) ON DEL)' in
>   /home/digitales/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234 error
>   while re-indexing Category product in Magento.

I am reindexing using php indexer.php --reindex catalog_category_product command from command-line.

I have tried the query -

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_product WHERE
product_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);
```

which is giving 0 results.

Also tried

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_category_product WHERE 
category_id not in (select entity_id from catalog_category_entity);
```

which is also giving 0 result.

Thanks,
Jen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend running the Magento DB repair tool as this will correct many common foreign key constraint issues and/or missing tables.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool

More than likely you have deleted a product and then left something in the Catalog_Category_Product_Index which is causing it to fail. First run a Database backup then run the following selects on your database:

```
SELECT * FROM Catalog_Category_Product_Index WHERE product_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM Catalog_Product_Entity)
```

Delete those rows from your database and the index process should work.

The below may help you understand the error in further detail:

Reading `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` describes the following:

```
FK -> Foreign Key
CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX -> Table Catalog_Category_Product_Index
PRD_ID -> Column Product_ID from Catalog_Category_Product_Index
CAT_PRD_ENTT -> Table Catalog_Product_Entity
ENTT_ID -> Column Entity_ID from Catalog_Product_Entity
```